# Get currency exchange rate in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server, I have...

AccDocumentItems Table:

```
SLId    DL1Id   DL2Id   Debit   Credit  CurId ExchangeRate  Cnt    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S1        D1     D4     2000      0       1      1000        2  
S1        D1     D4       0     6000      1      1500        4  
S1        D1     D4     6000      0       1      1200        5  
S2        D2     D4     4000      0       2      1000        4  
S2        D2     D4        0    2000      2      1000        2  
S2        D2     D4     3000      0       2      1500        2
```

I am trying to write a query in sql that group by `CurId` then substract  `Cnt` column that has debit greater than `0` from `Cnt` Column that has `Debit` `0`,for example row `1` to `3` has `CurId`  `1` and row `1` has `Debit` greater than zero,then we have `(2-4+5)=3` and row 4 to 6 has `CurId` `2` then we have `(4-2+2)=4`  finally I want sum of them `3*Last ExchangeRate` in `ExchangeRates` Table, and `4*Last ExchangeRate` in `ExchangeRates` Table, then sum of `(3*Last ExchangeRate+4*Last ExchangeRate)`.

ExchangeRates Table:

```
CurrencyId    EffectiveDate         ExchangeRate   
------------------------------------------------
 1            2016-1-1               1000
 2            2016-1-2               1200
 2            2016-1-3               2000
 1            2016-1-4               1500
```

> result=(3*Last `ExchangeRate`+4*Last `ExchangeRate`)-((sum of `Debit`)-(sum
>   of `Credit`))

in this example Last `ExchangeRate` for `CurrencyId` 1 is 1500, and Last `ExchangeRate` for `CurrencyId` 2 is `2000` finally I want this result

result=(3*1500+4*2000)-(15000-8000)

Comment: I;m totally confused.. you said  _3*Last ExchangeRate in ExchangeRates_ but where is ExchangeRate column in ExchangeRates table. It is in `AccDocumentItems` table. Please edit the question and make it clear

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: `group by CurId then substract  Cnt column that has debit greater than 0 from Cnt Column that has Debit 0` - This is the opposite of your logic, which subtracts `cnt` when `debit=0` and sums `cnt` when `debit>0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is based on your calculations and works only with 2 CurId's.

```
declare @cur_1 int = 1
declare @cur_2 int = 2

;with AccDocumentItems as (
    select
        *
    from
        (values 
            ('S1','D1','D4',2000,0,1,1000,2)
            ,('S1','D1','D4',0,6000,1,1500,4)
            ,('S1','D1','D4',6000,0,1,1200,5)
            ,('S2','D2','D4',4000,0,2,1000,4)
            ,('S2','D2','D4',0,2000,2,1000,2)
            ,('S2','D2','D4',3000,0,2,1500,2)
        ) t (SLId, DL1Id, DL2Id, Debit, Credit, CurId, ExRate, Cnt)
)
, ExchangeRates as (
    select
        *
    from
        (values
            (1,'2016-1-1',1000)
            ,(2,'2016-1-2',1200)
            ,(2,'2016-1-3',2000)
            ,(1,'2016-1-4',1500)
        ) t (CurrencyId, EffectiveDate, ParityRate)
)

select
    sum(t.cnt * q.ParityRate) - sum(diff)
from 
    (
        select
            CurId, diff = sum(Debit) - sum(Credit),  cnt = sum(cnt * case when Debit = 0 then -1 else 1 end)
        from
            AccDocumentItems
        where
            CurId in (@cur_1, @cur_2)
        group by CurId
    ) t
    join (
        select
            top 1 with ties *
        from
            ExchangeRates
        order by row_number() over (partition by CurrencyId order by EffectiveDate desc)
    ) q on t.CurId = q.CurrencyId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't have cur_1 and cur_2

Comment: I have limited solution with two parametres because of your expected output. You are getting only one expression that can be calculated only with two `CurID's`. You haven't showed what will be your output if there are 4 different `CurID`. Will you calculate for ear pair like (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4) or just 2 pairs (1,2),(3,4)?

Comment: currency id is distinct CurrencyId in  ExchangeRates  Table

Comment: CurrencyId in ExchangeRates Table is NOT distinct according to your sample data. But that is not main thing. Question is what output do you expect if there are 4 different CurrencyId's in AccDocumentItems table?

Comment: group by CurrencyId then sum(cnt)*lastParityRate-(sum(debit)-sum(credit))

Comment: Please update your question with more sample data and expected output if this solution does not work for you

Comment: Thank you so much for that quick answer - it makes perfect sense. And yes I've just verified.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for All CurId's.

```
Declare @Result int
Declare @DeCr   int
Declare @Cur    int

Set     @DeCr = (
                    Select  SUM(Debit)-SUM(Credit)
                    From    dbo.AccDocumentItems
                )
Set     @Cur = 
                (
                    Select   Sum(ParityRate * Zarib)
                    From
                    (
                        Select  ExchangeRates.CurrencyId as cuur,ParityRate
                        From
                            (
                                Select  Max(EffectiveDate) As MaxDate,CurrencyId
                                From    dbo.ExchangeRates
                                Group by CurrencyId
                            )As Table1
                        left join
                            dbo.ExchangeRates
                        ON  table1.currencyid = ExchangeRates.CurrencyId
                        And Table1.MaxDate  = EffectiveDate
                    ) As Table3
                    inner join
                    (
                        Select  Curid
                        ,       sum(cnt*signs) As Zarib
                        From
                        (
                            Select  CurId
                            ,       Cnt
                            ,       Case
                                        When Debit = 0 Then -1
                                        Else                1
                                    End As Signs
                            From    dbo.AccDocumentItems
                        ) As Table2
                        Group by Curid
                    )  As Table4
                    On  Table3.cuur = Table4.Curid
                )

Select  @Cur - @DeCr
```

Comment: Merci Majid, In khoruji dorost nemide.

Comment: kojash ro irad migire ? , man daghaghan hamon jadavel vm dorost kardam va javab dorost midad

Comment: kheili motshakeram babate zahmati ke keshidi, in query -369700 barmigadune, dar sourati ke javabe dorost (3*1500+4*2000)-(15000-8000) yani 5500

Comment: dovomi ke ferestadam ro bebin , daghighan javabesh 5500 mishe , (Select @Result ) ro ejra koni 5500 barmigardoone ,                                                 , khasti to telegram payam bede ta aksesh ro beferestam (@kadkhodamajid)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Result int
Declare @DeCr   int
Declare @Cur    int

Set     @DeCr = (
                    Select  SUM(Debit)-SUM(Credit)
                    From    dbo.AccDocumentItems
                )
Set     @Cur = 
                (
                    Select   Sum(ParityRate * Zarib)
                    From
                    (
                        Select  ExchangeRates.CurrencyId as cuur,ParityRate
                        From
                            (
                                Select  Max(EffectiveDate) As MaxDate,CurrencyId
                                From    dbo.ExchangeRates
                                Group by CurrencyId
                            )As Table1
                        left join
                            dbo.ExchangeRates
                        ON  table1.currencyid = ExchangeRates.CurrencyId
                        And Table1.MaxDate  = EffectiveDate
                    ) As Table3
                    inner join
                    (
                        Select  Curid
                        ,       sum(cnt*signs) As Zarib
                        From
                        (
                            Select  CurId
                            ,       Cnt
                            ,       Case
                                        When Debit = 0 Then -1
                                        Else                1
                                    End As Signs
                            From    dbo.AccDocumentItems
                        ) As Table2
                        Group by Curid
                    )  As Table4
                    On  Table3.cuur = Table4.Curid
                )

set @result = @Cur - @DeCr
Select @result
```